# Fob Key Pads Indicate Reception of Correct Key But do not Open

Tags: user-interface

What is the cause of the following "error" or dysfunction with fob (electronic keychain remote) secured doors:

When swiping the correct key for building doors secured by fobs, sometimes if you swipe your key too fast the fob indicates it has received the swipe by emitting the audible receive key signal (such as a beep) however, the door does *not* unlock.

Logically speaking, the receive key signal to the user (the beep) should not be emitted unless the fob has in fact received the key. Also, if the fob received an inconclusive swipe, it should not emit the beep to the user. What is happening with fobs in this case. I have observed this with many different fob secured doors on buildings. It appears to be a common signal/communication problem.

Comment: It probably only transmits while the button is held down and doing it too quickly doesn't allow the full code to be transmitted.

Comment: @jsotola FOB means "freight on board" and is commonly used when shipping goods in the United States. Sorry, you are right. :) The OP should not use jargon or vague terminology.

Comment: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fob (#3) Meaning in modern times has been extended to electronic remote attached to your keychain. Not an acronym, should not be all caps.

Comment: `if the fob received an inconclusive swipe, it should not emit the beep` ... you are making an assumption that the fob is read only once ... you are also making an assumption that the beep is emitted only on the last read and not emitted on every read ... my guess is that the fob is read several times, so that an accidental proximity of the fob does not open the door ... my other guess is that the programmer wrote the code to enable the beep with successful read ... the second and third reads occur while beep is already active from the first read, so no additional beep is heard

Comment: The use of fob referring to a watch fob goes back to [1888](https://www.webopedia.com/definitions/key-fob/).  Key fob sprung from that and predates the electronic ones.  They just happen to be a fob because it's a convenient form factor for a control device.  It naturally goes with your keys.